# Powershell escape character ` (backtick) not escaping string

Tags: powershell, escaping, literals

I'm having trouble adding a new line into a string in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\matt\Desktop\CShell Install" |foreach {'<Component Id="'+$_.name+'" Guid="' +[guid]::NewGuid() + '">`r`n<File Id="'+$_.name+'" Source="$(var.CShell.TargetPath)"></File></Component>'}
```

As you can see I want a newline to occur at

``r`n

instead they are printed literally.

Any pointers?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Powershell, but, it's usually `\r\n`.

Comment: Single quotes string have only one valid escape sequence `''` (strictly saying there are five valid single quote characters in PowerShell, so you have 25 valid escape sequences), anything else, including backtick, interpreted literally.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Could you elaborate, double backticks are also being interpreted literally

Comment: @m.edmondson Double backticks in single quote string `'``'` produce string with double backticks, so them interpreted literally, as you can see.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not use Single Quote, where you want PowerShell to honor backticks (or any other characters that you need PowerShell to interpret).

```
"FirstLine`r`nSecondLine" prints
FirstLine
SecondLine

'"FirstLine`r`nSecondLine"' prints
"FirstLine`r`nSecondLine"
```

Comment: This was the trick, remembering to also escape the double quotes I wanted as literal.  Thanks.